# Pyserial only works with opencv when readline() is used

Tags: python, opencv, arduino

So, I am creating a program that calculate some degrees based on opencv and then sends them to an Arduino using pyserial for a servo to rotate. The problem is this only works when ser.readline() is used which slows down opencv a lot. I've tried using ser.flush() or even ser.read() but they don't seem to work. I've also tried adjusting timeout in the pyserial initialization which still doesn't make any difference.
This is the python code

```py
# For webcam input:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_pose.Pose(
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue
    # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
    # pass by reference.
    image.flags.writeable = False
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pose.process(image)

    if not results.pose_landmarks:
      continue
    image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape

    try:
      angle = calculate_degrees(results)
      ser.write(str(angle).encode())    # Draw the pose annotation on the image.
      # Said readline
      ser.readline()
    except:
      pass
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
        image,
        results.pose_landmarks,
        mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
        landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
    # Flip the image horizontally for a selfie-view display.
    cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Pose', cv2.flip(image, 1))
    if cv2.waitKey(5) and 0xFF == 27:
      break
cap.release()
ser.close()
```

and here is the arduino code

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  servo.attach(7);
  servo.write(0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if (Serial.available()){
      String angle_string = Serial.readString();
      Serial.print("Recieved Value: ");
      Serial.println(angle_string);
      int angle = angle_string.toInt();
      servo.write(angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the actual problem is here. It seems some delay is needed for opencv code to work, but it's unclear how it doesn't work. `ser.readline()` delay is a result of `Serial.readString()` on the Arduino timing out (default 1 sec) and printing data back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the OpenCV part,but by changing the baud rate of Arduino can speed up data receiving and transmitting.

Change

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

to

```
Serial.begin(115200);
```

If this doesn't help.I suggest you to use a Raspberry Pi to do this project.By using the GPIO of RPi,you can interact with your servo directly and with no delay.

Update:
You need to add a delay of 15~20ms after `servo.write(angle);`to let the servo move to its position.

Here is a simple program that I wrote to test my servo.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  

String inString="";
int val;    

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(22);  
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
  inString = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');     
  val = inString.toInt();
  Serial.println(val);
  myservo.write(val);               
  delay(15); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Waiting `Serial.readString()` to time out and return data for `ser.readline()` to read, has nothing to do with baudrate.

Comment: If I were to use a raspberry pi, how accurate would the servo control be?

Comment: @OPSyKI as accurate as arduino. Since they both use PWM pin to control the servo.

Comment: @gre_gor  If I use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n');` rather than `Serial.readString();`.
Will it cut off the 1sec delay? Since it ends reading when it read `\n`.

Comment: OP isn't sending new lines, so that will just wait to timeout too. And reading back isn't really necessary, since nothing is done with the received string. Seems OP's code just doesn't work without some delay.

Comment: I think you're right, without that 15ms delay, the servo won't rotate properly.
I've tested it before.

Comment: I've added the delay but the result is still the same; it doesn't work without readline().